# Importance of knowing if a standard library function is executing a system call

Tags: system-calls

Is it actually important for a programmer to know if the standard library function he/she is using is actually executing a system call? If so, why?

Intuitively I'm guessing the only importance is in knowing if the general standard function is a library function or a system call itself. In other cases, I'm guessing there isn't much of a need to know if a library functions uses internally a system call?

Answer (score 2):

As a programmer you should be interested in what the function call *does*, not *how it is done*. Sure, one can be curious about such things. But if a particular function does (or could) invoke a system call or not is very much system-dependent.

Comment: Some "system-calls" may actually not be system calls per se: [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two situations in which you might need to care about what the library function is doing:

1. You discovered a bug in the function, and you verified this via some test cases.
2. The function is causing you performance problems, and you verified this via appropriate profiling.

As a general rule, though, it doesn't really matter what the library is doing, so long as it isn't causing you any trouble.